# Taylor Series Expansion of $\frac{1}{\sin 2x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do you find the Taylor expansions of the expressions: 
 $\frac{1}{sin2x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$
I'm not sure what to do since all the terms are in the denominator.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I suggest look at the related text books

Comment: At what point do you want to find Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the case to consider Laurent series, since both functions have a simple pole in zero.

By definition:
$$ \frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n \tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!}(-1)^n x^{n-1} \tag{2} $$
as well as:

$$ \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{2i}{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}=\frac{1}{2x}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{2n+2}(2^{2n+1}-1)4^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\, x^{2n+1}.\tag{3} $$
See [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any way to use more elementary methods, I have seen the Laurent series before, but I don't think I'd be expected to use it to answer this question. I've seen people elsewhere suggesting to compute the Taylor expansion of $\frac{x}{sin2x}$, then divide by $x$, but I'm not sure how you would find the Taylor expansion for that either, there will still be a pole at $0$ surely?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a few terms of the series expansion, consider the expansion of the denominator and perform the long division. This would give $$\frac{1}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{7 x^3}{45}+\frac{62 x^5}{945}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ $$\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{12}-\frac{x^3}{720}+\frac{x^5}{30240}+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Otherwise, already knowing that there will be a term $x^{-1}$, you could write $$\sin(2x)\sum_{i=-1}^\infty a_ix^i=1$$ $$(1-e^{-x})\sum_{i=-1}^\infty b_ix^i=1$$ replace $\sin(2x)$ and $(1-e^{-x})$ by their respective series expansion and identify for a same power of $x$ lhs and rhs.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MadChickenMan. You are very welcome ! By the way, nice user name !! Cheers :-)