# Expansion of $\frac{1}{(1 - e^{-x})}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

As Taylor's series give $e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$

Similarly, can someone please help me to find expansion of the term $\frac{1}{(1 - e^{-x})}$? Where $0 < e^{-x} < 1$

Thank you.

Comment: 1. If you expand about $0$, you get a Laurent series. 2. The coefficients are related to Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the response. If $0 < e^{-x} < 1$ then how to do this?

Comment: Use the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I found the answer at [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364905/taylor-series-expansion-of-frac1-sin-2x-and-frac11-e-x) shares by @JoséCarlosSantos